# Is it possible to change subnet in EC2 without terminating the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet

I'm fairly certain that it isn't but I want to be 100% sure if this is the case.
I looked over the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html#subnet-deleting) and it just mentions that we absolutely have to terminate the EC2 before deleting it but there's no mention of swapping the subnet. I thought this would be pretty common scenario when you start an instance in one of the default subnet but later need to swap them out with another for other reasons. But I'm finding it hard to find a clear answer to this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you stop, snapshot, then create a new instance in another subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an EC2 instance is launched, it's VPC and subnet cannot be changed.

The only way to "move" it is to create an AMI image, launch a new one in the desired subnet, and terminate the old one.